# Morphology and syntax

Tags: morphology

Can you explain the  definition of free and bound base in term of morphology  and give me some examples. I do not understand

Comment: Do you mean free and bound morphemes?

Answer (score 2):

A base is the part of a word that carries the core meaning and to which elements called affixes may be added to change the meaning.  *Free bases* may stand alone as words by themselves.  For example, *love* is a word, and it's the base for love*s*, lov*ed*, love*r*, love*sick*, etc.

The base *vert* comes from the Latin *vertere* (to turn), but it can't stand alone as a word that has anything to do with turning.  It is thus a *bound base*, one that exists only embedded with its affixes, as in *re*vert, *di*vert, *per*vert*ed, and so on.